# How to disable HTML formatting using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I'd like to generate an input field that is **able to "copy" it's value** **into another element** (in my case paragraph).

All is working so far but I got massive problems when I try to input some text strings like ...

```
< b> text < /b> // without the space columns
```

---

```
multiple backslashes
```

... or other HTML attributes / tags...

because changing the `innerHTML` will format this text into HTML text. But I want to use plain text including these tags / special characters instead.

```html
Input some HTML text<input oninput="out1.innerHTML=this.value" type="text" placeholder="input text">

<p id="out1"></p>


----------------------------------------------------------<br><br>
Change this text:
<input oninput="out2.innerHTML=this.value" type="text" value="<b>x</b> \\ %&">

<p id="out2"></p>
```

> How can I disable HTML formatting in this specific case `(to copy exact the same text into the paragraph element without styling)` without using a textfield / a second input field instead?

I thought about using `.html()` with jQuery but there also must be some more efficient way using only javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try using [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Because as the docs are saying:

> Element.innerHTML returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use innerHTML. However, textContent often has better performance because the text is not parsed as HTML.

```html
Input some HTML text<input oninput="out1.textContent=this.value" type="text" placeholder="input text">

<p id="out1"></p>


----------------------------------------------------------<br><br>
Change this text:
<input oninput="out2.textContent=this.value" type="text" value="<b>x</b> \\ %&">

<p id="out2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `.innerText` rather than `.innerHtml`. This references [the rendered text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText). innerHtml, on the other hand, [sets HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) here, not simply text nodes.